# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound because Controller class not included in war

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

(Please see update below)

I've been struggling with this issue for ages now.
I'm following John Purcival's tutorials for the Spring MVC Framework.
I've set up a `DispatcherServlet`, a `Controller` and a `ViewResolver` exactly as described in the tutorial series, however when I run the application, it gives me the following error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

I've gone through countless StackOverflow questions relating to the same issue but none of them has worked for me so far. I'm at my wits end now.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>spring-tutorial-50</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**offers-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me.spring.web.controllers">
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**OffersController.java**

```
package com.me.spring.web.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class OffersController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("name", "Borris");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsps/home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi there!

Session: <%= session.getAttribute("name") %> <p/>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the `deploy path` of my server by following [these](https://coderanch.com/t/543485/TomCat-running-Eclipse-shows-cached) steps:

> In Eclipse, you can change that deploy folder to something else.
>
> - Remove all the projects assigned to tomcat or you won't be able to change the setting (right-click the server / Add and Remove ...).
> - Do a Clean (right-click the server / Clean ... ).
> - Double-click the server to open the config page.
> - In the server location section, select "use Custom location" and specify a folder of your choice as the server path. You can leave
>     "wtpwebapps" as the deploy folder. I usually set something like
>     "C:\virtualTomcat" as the server path.
> - Save the file, do another clean and add your projects back to the server (right-click the server / Add and Remove ...).

I've now discovered that the OffersController isn't compiled; in other words:

`${serverDeploymentDirectory}/wtpwebapps/${projectName}/WEB-INF/classes/com/me/spring/web/controllers/`

is empty

Comment: The servlet is mapped to `/`. The controller is mapped to `/`. It seems the webapp is deployed as the root webapp (confirm this), so also mapped to `/`in the container. So why are you using `/offers/` to access your controller? Go to `http://localhost:8081/`.

Comment: Try http://localhost:8081/

Comment: I'm accessing "http://localhost:8081/offers/" because the context root of my application is "offers". I tried "http://localhost:8081" but still got 404

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by completing the following steps:

1. Right-click on project. Click on `Properties -> Deployment Assembly`. Remove the circled entry from `Deployment Assembly`

[Remove entry target/m2e-wtp/web-resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCa47.png)

2. Click on the `Servers` tab. Click on the small arrow to the left of the Server name. This will display a list of deployed projects. Right-click on the project in question and then select `Clean Module Work Directory`
3. Select the root directory of the project. From the Toolbar, select `Project-Clean`
4. Right-Click the root directory of the project. `Run As -> Run on server`